# An error occurred while installing ZenTest (4.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, zentest

**When I practice the Chapter three of the tutorial of Ruby on Rails. After mostly static pages: conclusion. I tried to push my app to heroku but an error showed up as below: (I searched this error everywhere but can not get a solution)**

```
Counting objects: 96, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (73/73), done.
Writing objects: 100% (79/79), 8.92 KiB, done.
Total 79 (delta 35), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.1
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (0.8.7)
       Installing ZenTest (4.8.2)
       Gem::InstallError: ZenTest requires RubyGems version ~> 1.8. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself.
       An error occurred while installing ZenTest (4.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install ZenTest -v '4.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:stark-tundra-9366.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:stark-tundra-9366.git'
```

**My Gemfile is like this:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

gem 'sqlite3', :group => [:development, :test]

gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1'
gem "ZenTest", "~> 4.8.2"
gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

group :text do
  gem 'rspec', '2.11.0'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.2'
end
```

I don't know what's wrong with this app. I changed the Zentest version and put into test or production, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

ZenTest seems to have limited the newest rubygems allowed. The solution for it is to update ZenTest, as well as rubygems, as newest ZenTest seems to work better.